# How do I store an plist on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I want to store some user settings like selected image, etc.
How could I do that with an plist?

Answer (score 3):

For basic settings you can use NSUserDefaults. If you need something more complicated (serializing objects) then you should write out and read in a data file.